# How to test angular-ui-Selectize using Protractor?

Tags: angularjs, protractor, angular-ui

I want to test a simple user creation form which contains a few dropdown controls (each one is the angular-ui-select)

I didn't find any doc on how to select one of the items..

this is my html:

```
<ui-select ng-model="user.assignedGroup" theme="selectize" class="dropdown">
                            <ui-select-match placeholder="{{::strings('userDetails.assignToGroupPlaceHolder')}}">{{$select.selected.name}}</ui-select-match>
                            <ui-select-choices repeat="group.name as group in groups">
                                <span ng-bind-html="group.name | highlight: $select.search"></span>
                            </ui-select-choices>
                        </ui-select>
```

I was able to get the dropdown list open by:

element(by.model('user.assignedGroup')).click();

What's next??

**EDIT**

The current solution I found is using typing and searching for a specific element and "hit" the enter key, but it's not the way I want to test this control. I have a dropdown control that is not searchable as well....

```
var selectGroupButton = element(by.model('user.assignedGroup'));
        var selectInput = selectGroupButton.element(by.css('.ui-select-search'));

        // click to open select
        selectGroupButton.click().then(function(){
            // type some text
            selectInput.sendKeys('group1\n');
        });
```

Answer (score -2):

You can access child elements using different css selectors, for example:

```
$('.dropdown ui-select-match:first-child');
```

And after that you can achieve behaviour that you want.

I would recommend you to look here: 
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp